# Create a reusable sequence (e.g. modal wizard) of screens that can be navigated to from different screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use react-navigation to design a reusable sequence of screens (a modal containing a multi-screen, wizard-like flow). I want to navigate to this sequence from different screens and I want to be able to go back to the screen I entered the sequence from once the user clicks some button on the last screen of the sequence (popping the whole sequence from the navigation stack).

However, I don't think I can navigate() back because the screen sequence can be reached from several different places, thus I don't have a known screen key I can navigate to. How do I best design something like this? Do I have the wizard in an embedded navigator and navigate the parent back one step to "discard" that whole navigator when done? The recommendation seems to not use nested navigators, especially when using modals?